# How to add attributes to already existing graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am creating a network graph by passing 'Source', 'Target', 'Relationship' as a dataframe, i want to add attributes to some nodes in the above graph so i pass the attributes as a dictionary to the graph, i do not know how to add attributes to already generated graph, since i have multiple attributes, i should go with dictionary.

```
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(main_df, source='Source', target='Target', 
                                edge_attr='Relationship')

nx.set_node_attributes(graph, node_dict)
```

First i run the graph by passing the below parameters and then for that graph i pass the dictionary which has attributes. How to add attributes dictionary  to 'graph'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add a set of attributes to the `graph` G:

```
attrs_g = {'title': 'Random graph1', 'value': 0.00}
G.graph.update(attrs_g)
```

To add node attributes to node 0, and 1:

```
attrs_n = [(0, {'name': "zero", 'elev': 10}), \
           (1, {'name': "one", 'elev': 11})]
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attrs_n)  # where nx is networkx
```

To add edge attributes to edge (0 -> 1):

```
attrs_e = [(0, 1), {'link_name': "some name", 'weight': 100}]
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, attrs_e)
```